# how to get email notification while created new user in splunk server

Tags: splunk

"how to get email notification while created new user in splunk web server,
that
receipts should get notification that user has been created for you.
I am using splunk enterprise 9.0.

Answer (score 2):

This currently is not a feature of Splunk.  Go to https://ideas.splunk.com to make a case for it.